# What does the command "node ." do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

The README document of my node server instructs me to run this command on my command prompt.

```
node .
```

What does this command do? How does it start my node server?

My package.json contents are

```
{
  "name": "uber-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Move your app forward with the Uber API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "swagger"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.2.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.3.0",
    "swagger-tools": "0.9.*"
  }
}
```

Comment: It will look for server.js in your project directory and it will start your app..

Comment: @Subburaj my project directory does not have a server.js file

Comment: @RogenGeorge: Did you really provided an argument after node? Or that dot(.) was you put by mistake?

Comment: The dot `.` in unix means the current directory. So, it would execute the default file in the given directory (index.js)

Comment: @aarosil sorry what do you mean by 'the default file'?

Comment: Yea, I meant defalt file as mentioned by @RogenGeorge answer.  Just letting you know what the `.` meant in case didn't know :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

By default Node.js is trying to load a module located in the folder that you are passing to it as an argument (`.` - just bash variant of the current folder). Then it runs whatever is written in the `"main"` section of the `package.json` file found in this folder.

In your case, it'll try to run `node ./index.js`

Doc: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

**Good point from** [@djechlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339987/djechlin): if no `package.json` found in the folder or if no `"main"` section is present, then Node.js will try to run the `index.js` file in this particular folder you are passing.

Comment: I think index.js is default if package.json does not specify.

Comment: You are correct djechilin. index.js is a default file for many things like import statements in React as well.

Comment: In a loopback project it will automatically run server/server.js ! How does that work ?

Comment: @Sethunath check the `main` value in `package.json`. 
It says: `"main": "server/server.js"` that is how loopback works.

Comment: @YuriTkachenko Thank you for clarifying